# Is Solr best for "Did you mean" Just like Google?

Tags: indexing, solr, spell-checking

I want to build **spell/query correction** functionality. I have **49GB** of **indexed data** into **Solr**. I want to create a mechanism just like Google - "**Did you mean**".

**Example** - If any user asks any question/query into search then my system/application gives the correct query and will correct all the misspell word from query/question.

So, Is **Solr** is best for this functionality? Or Is there any other tools for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Is this beer the best beer of the world?

It depends!

The quality of the results from the solr spell checking functionality depends form your configuration and the language, you like to check.

And.. it depends on the data based on.

I spend a lot of hours to get an working environment for spechecking with solr (language: german). Finally only with the option "only more popular" this features gives an result with an satisfaction-rate of 75% .

What I'm trying to say: to find the best application for spell checking in your case: simply test several way.

Comment: @ The Bndr. You are trying to say that Solr is best way to do spell checking. Right ?

Comment: No, i'm trying to say, that it depends on your needs and your language, if solr is the right tool. So I would recommend you to try an simple solr setup and see if the results are good enough.